# Are there any tools to export/parse javadocs in simple way?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, documentation, javadoc

Are there any tools to generate text files or `csv` tables from javadocs?

The only tool I found was IDEA standard `.html` docs builder. However, it is hard to parse it's output.
I also found `com.sun.javadoc` library, but it is deprecated, complicated and more about static code analysis and I just want to copy all docs from the project

I'm trying to create program documentation in MS Word for my Java application (IDEA project). I decided to export all the javadocs as `.csv`, `.txt` or any other way, and then generate word document with table via `docx4j`. But I got stuck on the first issue of the plan

Comment: Maybe someone has met such a case? :(

Comment: maybe use another documentation generator like pandoc or doxygen (which has some export possibilities to RTF).

Comment: You could try using docx4j-ImportXHTML on the .html output

Comment: @albert, `pandoc` is amazing! Thank you! Guess I'll use it to solve this case. But I'll also learn about `docx4j-ImportXHTML` too, and then close question...

Comment: I would prefer doxygen especially for its completeness and its multi language posibilities, but that is a personal taste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I decided to do it in a half-manual way...

1. Generate HTML documentation via `IDEA > tools > Generate JavaDocs > for whole project`
2. Then, for each file in each package directory (`doc_root\<package name>\<class name>.html`) covert it using pandoc to docs: `pandoc <class name>.html -f html -t docx -s -o table.docx` (UPD. Online pandoc word generator https://www.onlineconverter.com/html-to-docx)
3. Open each file in MS Word, remove odd data, fix table columns margins and padding and add borders. Copy tables in one large document

[image: Finally, got standard formatted Word documentation!]